# Displacement ignores UV mapping

Tags: uv, displacement

Here's my problem with applied displacement modifier:

[image: With displacement]

[image: Without displacement]

As you can see, when I apply the displacement modifier, the surface is uneven as the texture is streched across every face differently. The only solution so far was to use Remesh on the object, so it divides the whole object to small even squares, but i don't like this solution since my pc runs of out memory.

I've unwrapped the part, and applied it on the displacement. However it does not work!

[image: Unwrapped]

Here're the settings:

[image]

What can I do to have the displacement texture spread evenly across all different-sized faces?

Purpoise is to have this texture on a 3D print.

Answer (score 0):

The part which led me to confusion was using the auto-generated noise texture:

[image]

!! Notice the **Size: 0.00**.

It basically means, the/bumps dots were to be extremely small no matter how many subdivisions i applied. After I increased the size to 0.1, problem was solved:

[image]